# Como detectar Requisição Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Existe alguma forma no PHP de detectar se a requisição feita é Ajax?

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: Uma possibilidade seria você acrescentar um ?ajax=1 no fim do URL na chamada, assim não precisaria depender de headers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sim tem:

***Código***

```
<?php

 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
 *// FOI AJAX   
}
```

---

***Com Função function()***

```
<?php

function isXmlHttpRequest()
{
    $isAjax = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] : null;
    return (strtolower($isAjax) === 'xmlhttprequest');
}

if (isXmlHttpRequest()){
  // FOI AJAX
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Para os interessados, a solução abaixo segue a mesma linha de raciocínio que a apresentada pelo Harry Potter, no entanto, possui melhor performance, haja vista simplesmente comparar um valor, sem a necessidade de tratá-lo:

```
function isXmlHttpRequest() {

    $header = ( array_key_exists( 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', $_SERVER ) ?
                  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] : '' );

    return ( strcmp( $header, 'xmlhttprequest' ) == 0 );
}
```

Porém, vale ainda salientar que esse tipo de verificação depende de uma informação que apesar de suportado pela maioria dos *frameworks* pode não estar disponível após o processamento da Requisição, como é o caso do de [versões antigas](http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5801) Dojo.

Se isso for um problema para você, para se ter 100% de garantia, você tem duas opções:

1. Enviar um valor GET/POST identificável pela sua aplicação.
2. Enviar manualmente esse *Request Header*. Com a jQuery, por exemplo, ficaria assim:

   ```
   $.ajax({

       type: 'POST', // Ou GET
       url: 'algum-arqiuvo.php',

       beforeSend: function( xhr ){
           xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest' );
       }
   });
   ```

> Não há necessidade de enviar esse cabeçalho manualmente com a jQuery pois ela já o faz. O fragmento acima apenas demonstra a forma de fazê-lo, haja vista ser possível enviar outros cabeçalhos personalizados, prefixados com **X-**

Se você enviar o cabeçalho manualmente pode otimizar ainda mais a função de verificação sem a necessidade de verificar a existência da informação, levar em conta o case da string e etc. Basta comparar o valor:

```
function isXmlHttpRequest() {

    return ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' );
}
```

Comment: Sempre bom saber que existe maturidade ao negativar pelo simples fato de poder fazê-lo.

Comment: Alguém negativou sua resposta ?

Comment: Infelizmente, sim. Curioso é que se tal pessoa negativou, algum motivo ela teve. Se eu escrevi algo errado é porque sou humano (ainda) então que ela mostrasse maior sabedoria e comentasse para que eu corrigisse (dando os devidos créditos) ou ela mesmo editasse.