# Tratar erros de get(403,404,405) com jquery

Tags: jquery, html5, vraptor

Estou utilizando history API para fazer load dos clicks no menu, em um div #conteudo, ok até ai tudo bem, porém estou tratando os erros pelo JQUERY mesmo olhem só

```
$('a').click(function() {
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }
     $('#conteudo').load($(this).attr('href'), function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
                {

         if(xhr.status == 403) { 
             $('#conteudo').load("/error/error403");

         }
         if(xhr.status == 404) { 
             $('#conteudo').load("/error/error404");

         }
         if(xhr.status == 405) { 
             $('#conteudo').load("/error/error405");

         }

 });

      return false;
    });
```

gostaria da opinião se isso é realmente viável, já que estou utilizando o VRAPTOR e só consigo imaginar essa forma de tratar os erros de forma "eficiente" alguém ai teve problemas ou consegue ver um possível problema?

caso isso seja relevante, se o controller não existe ele manda o erro de página não existente(404), se o usuário tenta acessar um método não permitido, retorna o 403(forbidden) e assim por diante..

**EDITADO para a pergunta 2:**

bem, tenho a seguinte estrutura

tenho o index.php que contém 2 divs

```
<div id="menu"> 
e <div id="conteudo">
```

quando carrega o index, ele puxa com o .load(/teste/menu) para a div=menu

e quando clico em algum link no menu, ele dispara a função que dá $("#conteudo").load(/teste/LinkClicado)

funciona perfeitamente, só que se eu digitar no navegado /teste/LinkClicado ou /teste/menu, ele vai simplesmente abrir só os respectivos sem a divisão correta, o linkClicado vai abrir só o html referente a ele sem o MENU em cima... e assim se eu abrir o link do /teste/menu, ele vai mostrar só o menu sem o conteudo

como faço para que quando abrir o /teste/LinkClicado ele abra a página COMPLETA que seria o /teste/index, porém na posição referente ao link digitado no caso /teste/LinkClicado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação de [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), se você comparar o valor do parâmetro de retorno **status** com a string *error*, você consegue determinar que a ação de carregamento resultou num erro.

Com isso, como parece que todos os seus URLs de erro mudam apenas quanto ao *HTTP Response Code*, bastaria concatenar à parte imutável da string ao código de status:

```
$('#conteudo').load($(this).attr('href'), function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
                {
    if( status == "error" ) {

        $( '#conteudo' ).load( '/error/error' + xhr.status );
    }
});
```

Atente apenas que você deve ter um fallback para caso a segundo chamada à [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), para o erro, também falhe e você tenha como depurar.

Quanto a segunda pergunta seu maior problema está na obstrusividade do JavaScript. Uma Aplicação Web deve funcionar apenas com o HTML e a programação do lado servidor. Depois é que você adiciona o CSS e o JavaScript.

Ou seja, sua programação do lad servidor, quando receber uma determinada URL vai ter que devolver como resposta ao browser tudo aquilo de que a GUI precise para funcionar, isso inclui menu e corpo.

Depois de a interface visual está pronta é que o JS passaria a deixá-la mais rica, permitindo a navegação dinâmica, por exemplo.

Comment: caraca, verdade nem tinha pensado neste detalhe, valeuuu

aproveitando o embalo, você recomendaria outra forma de controle ou está suficientemente "bom"?

Comment: Vou precisar de um pouco mais de contexto. A quê exatamente se refere?

Comment: adicionei na pergunta o edit, se puder dar uma olhada, agradeço, valeu

Comment: Entendi eu acho, colocaria um header no index, se o server receber header quer dizer q veio dos links clicados então faz como o programado, caso contrario o user digitou e deu enter, então envia alguma coisa q faca dar load no /menu, certo?

Comment: Talvez [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16698/como-detectar-requisicao-ajax/16728#16728) possa te ajudar a fazer um controle.