# Como identificar o tipo de requisição enviada para o servidor?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Não quero que minha pagina ajax.php exiba nada quando acessada pelo browser do usuário.

[image]

**AJAX.PHP**

```
<?
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
if (!$nome) {echo 'Escreva seu nome!';} else {
if (!$email) {echo 'Escreva seu email!';} else {
  if (!$senha) {echo 'Escreva sua senha!';} else {
    $conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ) );
    $exe = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente(nome, email, senha) VALUES (:nome, :email, :senha)");
    $exe->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
    $exe->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $exe->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
    $exe->execute();
    echo 'Obrigado!';
  }
}
}
?>
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Laboratório Social</title>
<style>
* {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: default;
  border: none;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px #09f inset;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}

#submit {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 316px;
  background-color: #09f;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#nometexto {
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 316px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#emailtexto {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 316px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#senhatexto {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #09f;
  width: 316px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#nome {
  background-color: #09f;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 296px;
}

#email {
  background-color: #09f;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 296px;
}

#senha {
  background-color: #09f;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 296px;
}

#details {
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>





  <h4 id="nometexto">Nome</h6>
  <input type="text" id="nome">

  <h4 id="emailtexto">Email</h6>
  <input type="email" id="email" autocomplete="off">

  <h4 id="senhatexto">Senha</h6>
  <input type="password" id="senha">

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Registrar">

  <p id="details"></p>







<script async defer>

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {

var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var senha = document.getElementById("senha").value;

var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }



xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    if (xmlhttp.responseText == "Obrigado!") {
      document.getElementById("nome").value= "";
      document.getElementById("senha").value= "";
      document.getElementById("email").value= "";
    }
  }
}



xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&senha=" + senha);

};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Veja [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16698/4337), pode ser aplicado ao seu contexto também.

Comment: Não deu certo, quando fiz isso o ajax também não conseguiu se comunicar com o php.

Comment: Ele detecta o ajax como se fosse usuario tbm.

Comment: Você definiu também o cabeçalho com `setRequestHeader`, como mostra na segunda resposta da pergunta que indiquei? Após isto, atualizei sua pergunta com o novo código caso não tenha sucesso.

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: Para fazer como o @PauloRodrigues disse você deve colocar isso `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");` depois de `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    if (!$nome) {echo 'Escreva seu nome!';} else {
        if (!$email) {echo 'Escreva seu email!';} else {
            if (!$senha) {echo 'Escreva sua senha!';} else {
                $conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ) );
                $exe = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente(nome, email, senha) VALUES (:nome, :email, :senha)");
                $exe->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
                $exe->bindParam(':email', $email);
                $exe->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
                $exe->execute();
                echo 'Obrigado!';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Ou usar o exemplo desse [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16698/como-detectar-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax) conforme o usuário [Paulo Rodrigues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4337/paulo-rodrigues) sugeriu.

```
<?php
function isXmlHttpRequest()
{
    $isAjax = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] : null;
    return (strtolower($isAjax) === 'xmlhttprequest');
}

if (isXmlHttpRequest()){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    if (!$nome) {echo 'Escreva seu nome!';} else {
        if (!$email) {echo 'Escreva seu email!';} else {
            if (!$senha) {echo 'Escreva sua senha!';} else {
                $conn = new PDO( 'mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true ) );
                $exe = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cliente(nome, email, senha) VALUES (:nome, :email, :senha)");
                $exe->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
                $exe->bindParam(':email', $email);
                $exe->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
                $exe->execute();
                echo 'Obrigado!';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Dessa forma você precisa acrescentar ao *Header* da sua chamada `AJAX` o item `X-Requested-With` ainda sugiro que você use o [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) pois pode haver caracteres coringas (por exemplo `&`) nos dados enviados.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xmlhttp.send("nome=" + encodeURIComponent(nome) + "&email=" + encodeURIComponent(email) + "&senha=" + encodeURIComponent(senha));
```